# Advice to edit this JS Plugin?

Tags: javascript

Complete novice, in need of a bit of advice to alter a JS plugin slightly.  Its a postcode lookup for a Shopify checkout, and I'd basically like some help to alter how some of the elements are displayed.

Currently it looks like this:

http://www.yourfilelink.com/get.php?fid=1085208

All I'm looking to do is swap the order of the Find Address button and the text input field, i.e text field left and button right.

Comment: What JS Plugin? Do you have any code we can see? What have you tried?

Comment: If it is in a `<td>` tag then just search for `<td>` non case sensitively in the javascript library. If there many more fields it will probably swap them all. This will be harder to do if it is a minified file. It would be better then to modify the position after it is finished running with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is the Allies integration to add PostCoder Web address lookup to Shopify:-

https://developers.alliescomputing.com/postcoder-web-api/integrations/shopify

The JS for this inserts the entire `<tr>` into the DOM, the templates for the HTML used starts around line 97 in the JS file. This template could be edited to swap the `<td>` tags around.

However this might also need some CSS to be added via the `checkout.scss` theme file.